# Why is the PHP code executing before the HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop

I've been learning PHP for some weeks and right now I'm writing a script that combines a MySQL database, OOP PHP and PHP sessions.

Right now, theres a bit on the website that shows your name if you're logged in (that is if the session variable is set), and a log-in box if you're not logged in.

```
 <?php
                if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    echo "<h3>Login</h3>
                     include("login.php");
                } else {
                    echo "<h3>Welcome</h3> ". $user->get_name();
                    echo"<br><a href='logout.php'>Log-out</a>";
                }
            ?>
```

Assuming there is a session, the code above should be outputting: 
`Welcome Alex!`

However, if I run it the result is:

```
Alex
Welcome
```

In order to quickly fix it, I found out that if I do:

```
 echo "<h3>Welcome</h3> ;
    echo $user->get_name();
    echo"<br><a href='logout.php'>Log-out</a>";
```

It fixes it. That is, if I break the statement into two echos and the texts outputs correctly. Of course I know that's probably not a good way to fix it, given that I need to add the following code:

```
echo "<img src='".$user->get_photo()." border='5''>";
```

and once again, the text of the image loads first.

The output is the image link in text, and that chrome icon that simbolizes that an image was not loaded.

[link to image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WicW.png)

Can someone help me out? Thank you! If any opther bits of the code are needed please tell me, I've only written what I think it's relevant but I might be wrong.

EDIT:

Code of "get_name()" function:

```
function get_name() {
            echo get_user_data($this->user_id,"name");
        }
```

Comment: Does the `$user->get_name()` function also include `echo` code? Show that function code.

Comment: Assume its just a typo but you are missing a `"` at end of this line `echo "<h3>Login</h3>`

Comment: It does bloodyKnuckles, added it. And it was a typo RiggsFolly, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`echo` does IMMEDIATE output. If you try to echo a function which itself does an echo, the function's echo executes FIRST. e.g.

```
function foo() {
   echo 'foo';
}

echo 'bar' . foo();   // output foobar
```

and executes as the equivalent of

```
echo 'foo';
echo 'bar';
```

Why? Because `echo` first has to construct the string being output. So before `bar` can be echoed, the parent echo has to call `foo()`. That function doesn't return anything, it simply performs its own echo. multiple `echo` calls do not coordinate with each other, so foo's echo does its output. then foo returns nothing to the parent echo, so you're doing `echo 'bar' . null`, and  output `bar`.

If you had this:

```
function bar() {
   return 'bar';
}

echo 'foo' . bar();
```

it would work as expected. The execution sequence would be:

```
$temp = bar(); // $temp gets string'bar'
echo 'foo' . $temp;
echo 'foo' . 'bar';
echo 'foobar';
-> output foobar
```

Comment: The function should then return the string. `return $myVar;`

Comment: you should `return` then text from the function - not `echo` it there.

Comment: Thank you Marc B! It did fix the issue. The get_name() function did have an echo itself, that was calling the function that was also echoing something from the database. Once again thank you all for the answers. I'll be reading a bit more into the echo/return and how to use them properly.

Answer (score 1):

change the structure of function get_name() to

```
function get_name() {
            return get_user_data($this->user_id,"name");
        }
```

and it would work fine

Comment: Yeah, got it thank you!the function get_name() itself was calling get_user_data that was also echoing something from the DB.