# Make function inside echo be outputted at formatted position

Tags: php, function, heredoc

I have tried many approaches to get this right, including all types of quoting, etc. I will give you my current code before explaining the situation.

```
function show_msgs($msgs)
{
    foreach($msgs as $msg) {
        echo '<div class="msg">' . $msg . '</div>' . "\n    ";
    }
}

function generate_msgBox()
{
    global $array;        

    $stackoverflow = 
<<<EOT
    <div class="container">
        <div class="msgBox">
            %s      
        </div>
    </div>
EOT;

    $stackoverflow = sprintf($stackoverflow, show_msgs($array));

    echo $stackoverflow;
}
```

generate_msgBox function currently outputs this when called:

```
<div class="msg">First message!</div>
    <div class="msg">Seconds message!</div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="alertBox">

        </div>
    </div>
```

However I need it to output this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alertBox">
        <div class="msg">First message!</div>
        <div class="msg">Seconds message!</div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting function directly inside echo that is enclosed by normal quotes and I got the same result.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400285/why-is-the-php-code-executing-before-the-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo in  show_msgs function works before  output of  generate_msgBox function - when you call it. just return string with result of function

```
function show_msgs($msgs)
{
    $ret = '';
    foreach($msgs as $msg) {
        $ret .= '<div class="msg">' . $msg . '</div>' . "\n    ";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. By the way, you missed '$' in front of 'ret'.

Comment: Beat me to the answer splash58! :P

Comment: @Reisclef  I don't like echo in functions - it's every time output without any control

Comment: Me either, what you did was exactly what I would have done. I was trying to test my theory (as the OP had tried lots of things) when I saw you'd answered it.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
function show_msgs($msgs)
{
    foreach($msgs as $msg) {
        echo '<div class="msg">' . $msg . '</div>' . "\n";
    }
}

function generate_msgBox()
{
    $stackoverflow = '<div class="container"><div class="msgBox">'.show_msgs().'</div></div>';

    echo $stackoverflow;
}
```

Comment: As I said in the OP, I have already tried that. It gives the same result.